# What happens when one user approves and two reject a suggested edit?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

User A rejects an edit. User B approves it, then User C rejects it again.

Does this have consequences for User B? Will they lose the right to approve/reject edits?

Comment: Concrete case is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19245263) when @gonczor was clearly right (i made this edit to my own answer again and it was approved). I dont want him to get harmed for being right.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214156/349538), if a user does this too many times and then fails an audit, it could lead to a review ban. But nothing happens if the user never fails an audit.

Comment: Thanks Glorfindel and πάντα ῥεῖ, both answers are helpful, i threw a coin which one to accept, the other one have my upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this have consequences for User B? Will he lose the right to approve/reject edits?

No, why should it be so? Disagreement is ubiquitous and natural, that's why more than a single OP is involved.

User B might fail on audits, which are frequently strayed in their review queue, this would have consequences of throttling and banning them from reviews.

Comment: can you explain "User B might fail on audits, which are frequently strayed in their review queue"? Does this mean Reviewers sometimes get edits which actually have not been made, in order to test if they correctly approve/reject it?

Comment: @Nils Exactly that, yes. Also if they had attracted attention of site moderators, through flags (as Glorfindel mentioned), they could be banned manually by these.

Comment: Note that review bans only happen automatically on the [six sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/323179) where review audits are enabled.

Answer (score 3):

There's no automatic process for this; just like people can disagree about a post, voting it down while others vote it up, people can disagree about a suggested edit as well.

If a user *habitually* reviews 'wrongly' and you notice this, you can flag one of their posts for moderator attention.

Comment: Are you referring to the 'flag' links on Questions/Answer? I am hesitating to test-click it because i dont know if this can be undone.

Comment: Yes, the Flag links opens a dialog. The flag is cast only after clicking the button in the bottom right corner of that dialog.